# CBC - know "why" a program is infeasible

Tags: python, linear-programming

I use CBC to solve different integer linear programming problems. For some of them, the set of constraints is such that there is no solution. In this case, I get something like this:

```
Problem is infeasible - 0.30 seconds
Infeasible - objective value -6832.50000000
```

Is there any way CBC can tell me somehow "why" the problem is infeasible? For example, I would be happy to have a minimal set of constraints that are incompatible.

Comment: Such situation might appear when the relaxed polyhedron (set of constraints where the decision varialbes are continuous) doesn't contain any integer point, hence the MIP-relaxation is feasible and there exists some objective value, whereas MIP itself is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, this functionality is not implemented in CBC.

#### Alternative software

There is support for this concept in [Cplex](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibmilogcpleoptistud/) and [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) though. For the latter i can confirm, that this works quite well (called *Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem (IIS)*). Gurobi is also available without costs if you are in an academic setting (your access-domain needs to be recognized as university) and your project qualifies as academic project (always better to check out the terms of usage yourself).

#### Custom implementation

If you want to implement this yourself, have a look at:

> O. Guieu and J.W. Chinneck (1999), "Analyzing Infeasible Mixed-Integer
>   and Integer Linear Programs", INFORMS Journal on Computing, vol. 11, no.
>   1, pp. 63-77.

or

> Ulrich Junker. 2004. QUICKXPLAIN: preferred explanations and relaxations for over-constrained problems. In Proceedings of the 19th national conference on Artifical intelligence (AAAI'04), Anthony G. Cohn (Ed.). AAAI Press 167-172.

The latter is implemented in [this Ruby wrapper for cbc](https://github.com/gverger/ruby-cbc)